# Differential Equation help.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say I've got an equation with a couple of variables like:

$$\dfrac{dy(x)}{dx}\ - \dfrac{r(x)y(x)}{g(x)}\ = p(x)$$

If I'm trying to find the value of $y(x)$ at a specific value of $x$, can I sub that value of $x$ into the differential equation before I solve it? I would normally use the integrating factor method, but I have functions where $\dfrac{r(x)}{g(x)}$ isn't able to be integrated, but I know their values at point I'm looking to find the value of.

Comment: No there is not much to do before you solve it. Here you can use integrating factor method. If you have BOTH $x$ and $y$ then you can get slope $y'$. That is the basis of Euler method for numerical solution.

Comment: Because I couldn't integrate the functions, I evaluated them, and then integrated when doing the integrating factor method - is that wrong? In the question I'm attempting, it sounds like it asks for an exact solution rather than an approximation.

Comment: Since this equation is linear, you can use integrating factors. Notice that integrating factors works up to our abilities to solve integrals; i.e if the function $\frac{r(x)}{g(x)}$ has an elementary antiderivative. However, plugging in $x_0$ before solving the equation won't do you any good, since you don't know what $y(x)$ is.

Comment: What if you knew an initial condition? Would that help - i.e. I know y(0).

Comment: @Sanya  using $(x_0,y_0)$ will give you $y'(x_0)$. But that's it, just the information at the starting point.

Comment: @Sanya Perhaps you need to back up and detail the question that lead you to this question.

Comment: @Maesumi, it's a homework piece, so I'm just trying to understand so I can give it a go myself. 

Can I conclude that if it's not possible to integrate $$\frac{r(x)}{g(x)}$$, then it's not possible to use the integrating factor method?

Comment: Say you had: $$\frac{dy(x)}{dx}\ - \frac{(sin(x)+cos(x))y(x)}{x-cos(x)}\ = 2\ $$

I would want to use the integrating method there, but I couldn't integrate (sin(x)+cos(x))/(x-cos(x))?

Comment: Yes, there are two integration steps in integrating factor method. If either one stalls then the solution will be left as an expression involving an integral that could not be done. You can always check [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to see if there is an well-known solution. This one does not seem to be doable there either.

Comment: I see; maybe I should use Euler's method then! I'll try that and see if I get something near what I want. Thanks for the help, Maesumi.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know what 
$$\left(\frac{dy}{dx} - p(x)\right)\frac{g(x)}{r(x)}$$
is for your particular $x$, then yes, you certainly can simply plug in $x$.

Comment: What if I only know p(x), g(x) and r(x)?

Comment: Then you're out of luck.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I must be doing something wrong.